# Interpreting output from a linear regression model?

Tags: r, regression, statistical-significance, p-value, interpretation

I've done a linear regression model to determine the effect of personality position on a scale and changes in reaction time. I adjusted for age as a confounding factor. I've got the output, but there are so many p-values that I don't know what each of them mean.

Here is the output:

[image]

More importantly, what does the p-value 0.03158 at the end signify?

Comment: Maybe see [here](https://statisticsbyjim.com/regression/interpret-f-test-overall-significance-regression/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go through each part one-by-one.

##### Call

The call section simply spits the formula back at you that was used when modeling your regression. There isn't really much to say about that other than it gives you what you already know.

##### Residuals

Recall that **residuals** are the errors in your model, or how badly your model guesses. These are standard for regression like the one you have. The **minimum** is the furthest your residuals are below the regression line, in other words how much your regression line overshoots it's prediction. The **maximum** is the opposite, which shows the value which undershoots the prediction the most. 1Q and 3Q are just quartile ranges of these residuals. The **median** should usually be somewhere close to zero (rarely is it exactly zero), as the average residuals should over time be close to where the regression line is fit.

##### Coefficients

These are simply all of the terms entered in the model. These usually include the intercept and your slopes (from the predictors you entered). The **intercept** for a Gaussian family regression such as this is generally understood as a *conditional mean* which is contingent upon the other terms in the model. We normally don't invest a lot of time in the point estimates in this row, as they don't usually in this case provide a lot of value.

Your **slopes** however tell you whether or not your predictors have some utility. For the "personality" predictor here, the estimate is the slope. For every $1$ unit increase in this predictor, we get a $-.005$ decrease in your outcome of "change RT". The standard error and *t* value here are both used to derive the significance of the slope, which is indicated by the last output in the row. For "personality" the *p* value is $.7329$ and consequently is not significant. Age however has a low *p* value and can be deemed "significant" (though this doesn't say much about how *strong* that effect is).

These coefficients can also be used to build a **linear equation**. Now that we have all of our coefficient values, we simply put them together into an equation like so:

$$
RT = .074 + (-.005 * Personality) + (.006 * Age)
$$

##### Signif. Codes

You can ignore these, as they simply designate which values are significant and are self-evident.

##### The Rest...

I imagine your confusion is the bottom output. The **residual standard error** is essentially how "precise" the model’s predictions are. A lower RSE is generally more precise, indicating your model is good at predicting. Multiple $R^2$ is the proportion of variance in the outcome explained by the predictors in your model. We typically use the adjusted $R^2$ instead if we have multiple predictors, as the first value can be inflated by simply adding a bunch of predictors in the same model. Here we can see in either case that the model predicts very little variance in the outcome. The bottom values are the model significance terms, which show the *f* value and degrees of freedom, which are used to test overall model significance. As indicated by Dimitri's link:

> "The F-test of overall significance indicates whether your linear
> regression model provides a better fit to the data than a model that
> contains no independent variables."

So this should give you an idea of what your output here is saying.